# How do I declare a file type for removable storage access in Windows UAP?

Tags: windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

I have a Windows Universal App with a declaration in the app manifest for removable storage access.  How do I declare the file type for the access ?

```
  <Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  <uap:Capability Name="removableStorage" />
  </Capabilities>
```

Comment: Did you check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh465187(v=win.10).aspx)?

Comment: Yes.  I'll try MSDN again.